# Get the owner object of an object

Tags: java, metaprogramming

I mean, is it possible to know the owner of an object in Java without saving a reference to the owner?

```
class Owner1 {
    Owner1(){
        new Child();
    }
}

class Owner2{
    Owner2(){
        new Child();
    }
}

class Child(){
    Child(){
        Object object = this.getOwnerObject(); 
        if(object instanceof Owner1)
        else if(object instanceof Owner2)
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not possible

Comment: Why not design your child so it explicitly holds a mandatory reference to it's "owner"

Comment: Because it would not be so clean. But it seems to be the only way.